# Python - matplotlib heatmap comparison with R

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, plot, scipy

I was trying to reproduce a [R - Heatmap](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/moac/people/students/peter_cock/r/heatmap/) to Python. After some search in Google I was able to do it, but still both the heatmaps plot doesn't look the same. I am using the same 2d matrix for both. The following is the R code for plotting and saving the image:

`R-Code`:

```
library("ALL")
data("ALL")
eset <- ALL[, ALL$mol.biol %in% c("BCR/ABL", "ALL1/AF4")]
library(limma)
f <- factor(as.character(eset$mol.biol))
design <- model.matrix(~f)
fit <- eBayes(lmFit(eset,design))
source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("limma")
selected  <- p.adjust(fit$p.value[, 2]) <0.05
esetSel <- eset [selected, ]
write.csv(exprs(esetSel[1:100,]), file="C://test/output.csv", row.names=TRUE)
heatmap(exprs(esetSel))
```

The following is the output image of R:
[image: R-Heatmap]

The following is the python-matplotlib code for generating the heatmap:

```
import scipy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
%matplotlib inline

def generate_heat_map(df, cmap="YlGnBu"):
    """
    Function to generate headmaps with dendrogram
    """

    # figure size
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    # need to change the line width
    # default line width doesn't look good
    matplotlib.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 0.5
    # axis to show where this current axis 
    # need to be shown
    ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.09, 0.1, 0.2, 0.6])
    # to generate the array the will be passed
    # to dendrogram, mey
    Y = sch.linkage(df, method='centroid')
    # need to make changes in orientation to
    # make it appear in the left
    # default is top
    Z1 = sch.dendrogram(Y, orientation='left')
    # removing x and y ticks
    ax1.set_xticks([])
    ax1.set_yticks([])
    # to remove the axis
    ax1.axis('off')

    # top side dendogram
    ax2 = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.71, 0.6, 0.2])
    Y = sch.linkage(df.T, method='ward')
    Z2 = sch.dendrogram(Y)
    ax2.set_xticks([])
    ax2.set_yticks([])
    ax2.axis('off')

    # main heatmap
    axmatrix = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0.6])
    # getting the index to get our required values
    # that needs to be shown in the heatmap
    idx1 = Z1['leaves']
    idx2 = Z2['leaves']
    D = df.values[idx1, :]
    D = df.values[:, idx2]
#     D = df.values
    # using matshow to display the heatmap
    # colormap: 'GnBu', 'PuBu', 'YlGnBu', 'PuBuGn', 'BuGn', 'YlGn'
    im = axmatrix.matshow(D, aspect='auto', 
                          origin='lower', cmap=cmap)
    axmatrix.set_xticks([])
    axmatrix.set_yticks([])

    # xticks to the right (x-axis)
    axmatrix.set_xticks(range(len(df.columns)))
    # this shows the required labels
    # in this case it is the dataframe columns
    axmatrix.set_xticklabels(df.columns, minor=False)
    axmatrix.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
    axmatrix.xaxis.tick_bottom()

    # to change the rotation of xticks
    plt.xticks(rotation=90, fontsize=8)

    # xticks to the right (y-axis)
    axmatrix.set_yticks(range(len(df.index)))
    # this shows the required labels
    # in this case it is the dataframe index
    axmatrix.set_yticklabels(df.index, minor=False)
    axmatrix.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
    axmatrix.yaxis.tick_right()

filepath = 'output.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col=0)
generate_heat_map(df)
```

The following is the output of Python-matplotlib:
[image: Python-heatmap]

What might be the problem. Is there any way to get a Python-matplotlib heatmap plot similar to R-Heatmap. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you think that the plot is wrong or do you simply not like the the clustering?

Comment: The matplotlib heatmap is not similar to R heatmap. Is it because of the clustering? Sorry I am new to this. Kindly help. @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: It looks different, yes. Is that the problem? Or do you think it is wrong? It's clear that scipy uses a different clustering algorithm that R does, but I don't think you can change that.

Comment: It looks different. That is my problem. If I try changing `method='ward'` will I be able to get some appropriate results? Thanks

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest When I changed the method I was able to get the dengrogram similar to R, but the heat-map doesnt look similiar to R. The method name was `"complete"`

Comment: Looking at the tick labels on the bottom x-axis the order on the matplotlib plot is ascending numerically, whereas the order on the R plot is not. So as mentioned by ImportanceOfBeingErnest it might be useful to try some of the different clustering methods listed here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage